# Side by side text on webpage HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to put text on this webpage http://www.freethemind.biz/

Where it says On a physical level, meditation: and everything listed as benefits

AND

On a mental level, meditation: and everything listed as benefits

side by side, almost like a table

I have tried

`float:left and float:right` in CSS

Code below:

```
h12{float:left;}
h13{float:right;}
```

But it does not work! I am very new to web page creation and all, so any direction is appreciated!
I also tried wrapping the text to be put side to side in tags `<h12>` and `<h13>` if it makes it any easier (didn't for me =[ )

Comment: *It does not work* is not particularly helpful. Please post the **minimum code required to replicate the problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying your HTML, you can achieve this with the following CSS:

```
h12, h13 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Note that [**heading tags only go up to `h6`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)! `h12` and `h13` are not standard tags, and will be [**unsupported in many browsers**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements). As such, you should look into using `<div>` tags instead, and apply a unique `class` to separate out this behaviour to only a few, specific elements.

```css
.floating {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating">
  <strong>On a physical level...</strong>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="floating">
  <strong>On a mental level...</strong>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks obsidian, would there be an documentation i can go through to learn html and css editing that you'd recommend? thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'd recommend [**W3Schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) to get a basic understanding of HTML concepts, and the [**W3C Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/) to confirm that your HTML is valid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `h12` and `h13` are non-existing HTML tags and thus invalid.

The following however works:

```
<div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
<strong>On a physical level, meditation:</strong><p></p>
<p>·       Lowers high blood pressure</p>
<p>·       Lowers the levels of blood lactate, reducing anxiety attacks</p>
<p>·       Decreases tension-related ailments such as headaches, insomnia, and muscle &amp; joint pain</p>
<p>·       Increases serotonin production that improves mood and behavior</p>
</div>
<div style="float:right;width:50%"><strong>On a mental level, meditation:</strong><p></p>
<p>·       Helps decrease anxiety</p>
<p>·       Leads to a calmer mind which in turn results in more concentration and clarity</p>
<p>·       Improves emotional stability</p>
<p>·       Increases creativity and Develops Intuition</p>
</div>
</div>
```

It is also a better practice to use `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>` to make lists instead of using `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap your 2 DIVs in another DIV.

You should consider cleaning up your markup though. Take a look at "HTML Document Outline".